# Does a C++ style cast operator change the pointer it casts?

Tags: c++, inheritance, pointers, casting, type-conversion

I am quite happy using the C++ style casting operators within my code but I cannot say that I **truly** understand what goes on behind the scenes. I am basically wondering what actually is happening to the pointer during the following short process:

```
class A {};
class B : public A {};
class C : public B {};

A* pC = new C();

B* b = static_cast<B*>(pC);    // Is the value of pC changed by the cast?
C* c = static_cast<B*>(pC);    // Is the value of pC changed by the cast?
B* b2 = static_cast<B*>(c)     // Is the value of c now equal to the value of b2?
```

I realise that the object pointed to by `pC` is always of type `C` but after the first cast is made, I assume that the address stored in `b` is no longer equal to that of `pC`. But if the cast changes the value of `pC` my assumption is wrong. In a nutshell, can the cast operators actually change the address of the pointer they cast? This may seem a pretty facile question, but in my mind the picture is just not clear of how objects with an inheritance hierarchy are stored within memory and how the pointers get manipulated via the casts.

In my head the value of `pC` remains unchanged no matter how many casts are performed on it but is this thinking correct?

Comment: It's a little unclear what you mean by "changed".  static_cast<> is a function.  It takes a value and returns a new value.  By "changed" do you mean that the new value might be different from the old value?

Comment: @VaughnCato I am expecting the new pointer that gets assigned by the returned cast to be different, what I wanted to know was does the cast affect the pointer passed to the cast (in this case pC). I used static cast as an example, but I really wondered if ANY cast is able to modify its pointer - I guess what I am asking is does the cast treat the argument like pass by value (or const ref) - ie cannot modify it.

Comment: Yes, the argument to static_cast<> is pass by value.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The casted pointer can point to another location. In case of multiple inheritance for example. [Good read](http://hacksoflife.blogspot.com/2007/02/c-objects-part-3-multiple-inheritance.html)

The original pointer will be preserved

Comment: I was waiting for this answer.

Answer (score 6):

In no case does a cast change its operand. All it does is to change how the compiler *sees* the operand.

The value of `pC` will not be changed; the *result* of the cast might be an identical value but different type (e.g. in the case of a `const_cast` or a `reinterpret_cast`), or it might actually be both a different type *and* a different value (e.g. in the case of a `static_cast` in a case of multiple inheritance, see Andrew's answer).

To really understand in which cases a different result value would happen, you would have to read up on C++ ABIs, i.e. how objects are stored in memory *exactly*.

Comment: While it is true that the operand is never changed, the result of `static_cast<int>(0.1)` doesn't mean that `0.1` is 'seen' any different.

Comment: @LucDanton: In the general case. E.g., a `reinterpret_cast<int>("123")` (oh, the humanity!) is "seen" as an int. The result of a `const_cast` is "seen" as non-const. That is what I was referring to.

Comment: 'In the general case' is much less strongly worded than 'in no case'. You may want to fix that.

Comment: @LucDanton: You are leaning heavy on a non-native speaker. I will try to reword it a bit, OK?

Comment: But that's what the comments are for, improving an answer :)

Comment: @LucDanton: The point is that I feel you are twisting words. *In **no** case does a cast change its operand.* I stand by this statement, to avoid the misconception that the operand of the cast itself - `pC` in the case of the first two examples, `c` in the third - is being changed. The *result* of the cast differs in type, and *might* differ in value, but I felt that the original answer was already clear on the subject.

Comment: I'm not twisting words. This was my honest reaction to reading your answer: I thought that you meant that not only does a cast *never* change the operand, it would also *always* be about changing how the operand is seen. Since that is not what you meant (you did say 'in the general case'), then in my mind the best course of action is to pick unambiguous wording. This has always been about improving the answer (since we're in the comments), I'm not inquiring about casts -- I know how that works.

Comment: +1 for you because I think you are the only one who answered the actual question (which could be reworded "Do casts modify their operand?").

Answer (score 6):

In your case, it doesn't change the pointer.

But for multiple inheritance, it will have to change the pointer.

You can write a sample program to confirm that.

Answer (score -1):

Short answer:

With casts you just tell the compiler how to interpret an object, i.e. of what type I is supposed to think the object is.

A cast does not change the value of an object.

Comment: While technically correct, your answer is misleading. Casting a pointer to a class instance may return a different pointer address than the casted pointer contains.